# Evaluating a css-variable by a declaration-block

Tags: css, css-variables

Accidentally, [I saw such CSS](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/breaking-changes/css-vars):

```css
:root {
  --flex-theme: {
    border: 1px solid #00F;
    padding: 3px;
  };
}
```

That was the first time I saw a complete [**declaration block**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS_Object_Model/CSS_Declaration_Block) (`{border: ...; padding: ...;}`) assigned to a CSS variable (`--flex-theme`).

---

How would this be usable?

Comment: That link says “ Even though these values might not be meaningful for any CSS property, they could be accessed from JavaScript”